# `testthat::expect_silent()` does not seem to notice ggplot2 errors

Tags: r, ggplot2, testthat

I'm having trouble understanding the following behaviour of the [`expect_silent()`](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/output-expectations.html) function from [testthat](https://testthat.r-lib.org).

`expect_silent()` is supposed to fail when the test code returns any output, for example an error or warning:

```r
library(testthat)

test_that("expect_silent works as expected", {
  expect_silent( {
    stop()
  } )
} )
#> Error: Test failed: 'expect_silent works as expected'
#> * 
#> 1: expect_silent({
#>        stop()
#>    }) at <text>:5
#> 2: quasi_capture(enquo(object), evaluate_promise)
#> 3: capture(act$val <- eval_bare(get_expr(quo), get_env(quo)))
#> 4: withr::with_output_sink(temp, withCallingHandlers(withVisible(code), warning = handle_warning, 
#>        message = handle_message))
#> 5: force(code)
#> 6: withCallingHandlers(withVisible(code), warning = handle_warning, message = handle_message)
#> 7: withVisible(code)
#> 8: eval_bare(get_expr(quo), get_env(quo))
#> 9: stop() at <text>:6
```

(The above is the expected behaviour: `expect_silent()` detects the error produced by `stop()`, and the test fails.)

However, for some reason it doesn't seem to detect errors that occur in ggplot2 expressions. For example, the following ggplot2 code produces an error due to a misspelling:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carrot, y = price)) +
  geom_point()
#> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): object 'carrot' not found
```

But `expect_silent()` doesn't seem to detect the error:

```r
test_that("expect_silent fails when ggplot2 throws an error", {
  expect_silent( {
    ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carrot, y = price)) +
      geom_point()
  } )
} )
```

(No output is produced.)

Am I misunderstanding the purpose of `expect_silent()`? This is causing me a real headache as I'm trying to use it to test a ggplot2 extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try capturing the output from ggplot and then testing if it can be printed:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(testthat)

# First test should succeed (no output)
test_that("silent when ggplot2 succeeds", {
  working.plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point()
  expect_silent(print(working.plot))
} )

# Second test should fail
test_that("fails when ggplot2 throws an error", {
  broken.plot <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = carrot, y = price)) + geom_point()
  expect_silent(print(broken.plot))
} )
```

The second test fails with copious output which I've curtailed below:

```
Error: Test failed: 'expect_silent fails when ggplot2 throws an error'
* object 'carrot' not found
```

**Update - 15th Dec 2018**

Regarding your comment about why print() is necessary:

The `ggplot()` function returns an object of class ggplot.  The ggplot2 package overloads the `print()` function, so instead of printing the object to STDOUT in the R session terminal, it prints the chart.  The interactive mode in the R session terminal assumes that most of the commands are run through the `print()` function.

The testthat tests are evaluated in their own environments.  The testthat environments are non-interactive, so the running through the `print()` function assumption no longer holds.  You can test this with the `interactive()` function that comes with base R.  It should report TRUE in the R session terminal and FALSE within a `test_that()` call.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Do you have any idea why it works with `print()` but not without?

Comment: No worries.  I've added an update to my answer regarding why print() is necessary with testthat tests.